# How can I change font leading (linespacing) in wxWidgets?

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

Then I use wxDC::DrawLabel for drawing multiline text I want to control font leading (linespacing). Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

There is no existing function to do that.

You can create your own.  Use `DrawText()` to draw the individual lines with the spacing you want, but you draw each line individually.  Use `GetTextExtent()` to find the height of the lines, and hence how much linespacing you'll need.